# Predicate to find core data parent object based on relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, predicate

I am trying to to use predicate to find a parent object (bank) based on the relationship with the child (transaction). I have used similar code in reverse to find transactions of a bank with no problems but never tried it in reverse before. The transaction is passed from a previous vc and displays correctly. Likewise, my [_banksListData count]is correct showing several banks, but after predicate shows 0.

Any suggestions or code in Obj c or Swift greatly appreciated

Here is my code -

```
//search banks for relationship with transaction
_banksListData = [CoreDataHelper getObjectsForEntity:@"Banks" withSortKey:@"name" andSortAscending:YES andContext:_managedObjectContext];
NSLog(@"banks count: %lu", (unsigned long)[_banksListData count]);

// banks count ok

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"bankToTransaction == %@", _transaction];

NSLog(@"bankForTransaction count: %lu", (unsigned long)([[_banksListData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] count]));

//after predicate- count is 0!!!! Why!!!!

if([[_banksListData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] count]>0)
  _bank = [[_banksListData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"transaction is for account: %@", _bank.name);
```

Comment: Your `Transaction` should have an inverse to-one relationship to the `Bank`, so you don't need to query.  The `Bank` can be obtained by simply accessing the `bank` property (or whatever you called the relationship) of the `Transaction`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In this case I am sorting transactions from several bank accounts into categories, and then passing one transaction to a new controller for editing. I don't have a reference to the bank account the transaction was originally derived from. My question is - how do I do the reverese query to get the bank account from the transaction?

Comment: Why don't you have the reference?  Doesn't your transaction entity have a reference to its bank entity?  If it doesn't then you should change your model so that it does. Core Data is not a relational database, it is an object persistence system. References in Core Data are not "foreign keys" they are actual references to the referenced object.  `someTransaction.bank` will give you the `Bank` object directly. There is no need to query